# file variable in dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js, file-handling

I am using dropzone.js to implement file uploading. I am new to JavaScript. Can anyone tell me what does the variable `file` store here? The name of the file?

```
accept: function(file, done) {
return done();
},
```

Moreover, I want to display the content of the file to the text area having `id="editor"`.

```
accept: function(file, done) {
document.getElementById('editor').value=file.text;
return done();
},
```

Ihave used `file.text` and also the `readAsText()`, but both of them are showing `undefined` in the text area. Is there any other easy way to do it?

This function is present in `dropzone.js` file.
OR is there any way so that i can use PHP functions like `file_get_contents()` in `.js` file and in JavaScript function ?

Answer (score 0):

The file parameter is an object - Just use console.log to check what data the object returns.

```
accept: function(file, done) {
    console.log(file);
    done();
},
```

If you are uploading your file through PHP and want to return the URL of the uploaded file to display in the text area, try this instead -

```
init: function() {
    this.on("success", function(file, data) { 

        // Log both the file object and server response
        console.log(file);
        console.log(data);

        // Remove the file from the dropzone so it doesn't clutter the UI
        this.removeFile(file);
    });
}
```

Where file is the object and data is the server response (You could return the URL of the uploaded file in PHP after passing the data to it as you would a regular form). I noticed you also tagged PHP, so I assume this is the intended purpose.

See http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration for usage of accept.

Edit:

To display the contents of a text file try this with your code -

```
var editor = document.getElementById('editor');

accept: function(file, done) {

    // Get the file contents - Load result into element
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      editor.innerText = reader.result;
    }
    reader.readAsText(file);  

    // Return done
    done();
}
```

Comment: but i want to display the contents of the file in the textarea. I think this can be done without originally uploading the file to the server. What i want to do is to drag and drop the file and the contents of the file will display on the textarea. the supported files types are .txt,.cpp,.c etc.

Comment: I've edited my answer for you - Sorry, I misunderstood the initial question! Hopefully it works, if not let me know.

Comment: but its not working when i am using ace editor in the textarea.

Comment: That's because ace editor has its own method for inserting text into the editor - Instead of editor.innerText = reader.result; you should use editor.setValue(reader.result);

Comment: not working! blank on the textarea! and when i am inspect elementing the textarea

Comment: Are you using the Ace Editor from this link? https://ace.c9.io/#nav=howto

Comment: Hm - I've tried this locally and it works. Is Ace Editor initialised properly? I'd advise reading the documentation since now it seems like the issue is with your set up of Ace Editor since we've verified that the code above works for a plain textarea. I'd also advise opening a new question if Ace Editor isn't working for you with the new code!